# meta method inject on Grails Controller

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming, grails-2.0

I wrote a plugin to inject a method into all controllers, I wrote this on          `doWithDynamicMethod {ctx -> }`

```
    for (classes in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.application.controllerClasses){
         def controllerClass = classes.clazz
         controllerClass.metaClass.static.doTestSearch << {args ->
             println "this is dynamic insertion -->"+args.toString()
         }
         classes.class.metaClass.doTestSearch << {args ->
             println "this is dynamic insertion -->"+args.toString()
         }
    }
```

When i tried to call this method in form in view, by :

```
<g:form method="POST">

<g:actionSubmit class="save" action="doTestSearch"
            value="${message(code: 'default.button.search.label', default: 'Search')}" />
```

The method doesn't called and returning a 404 error.

But when i tried to call it from controller by :

```
doTestSearch(params)
```

It works.

Can someone please explain why is this happening ? And can i call the dynamic method directly from view ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
application.controllerClasses.each {controller ->
controller.metaClass.doTestSearch = {
     //Your action code here
 }
}
```

BTW - you can use DynamicController plugin also for adding actions to controllers

Comment: sorry, but what's the difference between `application.controllerClasses.each {controller ->` and `classes in grailsApplication.controllerClasses`?

Comment: There's no difference, probably the difference is the 'static' You are adding a static closure property and trying to use it as action.

Comment: yes i do, does every method on controller is declared as non-static method ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like grails can't map the URL for the methods added at runtime but I haven't tested it.